# Excel Dynamic Growing Rows

Tags: excel, dynamic, row

I've been looking for hours to solve this but I just can't find an answer.

I have an excel table, and I have another sheet with a partial copy of that table.

Now what i want is when I add a row in my first table (Please note that there is also text below this, but I can put a mark there or something similar to mark that it should end there), that my other table would also add the same amount of rows (Also please note that my second table has text below).

I have no idea how to do this, what would be the best approach?

I'm not even sure what I ask is making sense.

So let me try again in different words:

Sheet 1:

- Some text
- My rows
- Some text

Sheet 2:

- Another text
- My rows
- Other text

if i add rows in sheet 1, i want them to be also added to sheet 2.

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Would a suitable answer simply allow you to Insert the same number of rows, in each table? I.e., you run a macro that asks you A) how many rows to insert, and B) at what row to begin insertion; then the rows are inserted in both tables, appropriately.

Comment: If not, then [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80626-insert-row-event.html) might get you started.

Comment: @DavidZemens first comment is a good point to start. Alternatively one could use events to control and do what you need. WtFudgeE, you didn't tag this question with VBA and proposed solutions won't work without macros. How do you find it. Possibly add some screen shot presenting what you exactly need.

Comment: @KazJaw +1 both suggestions will require VBA or event macros. second comment pertains to events :) is there a simple way to trap the row insert event?

Comment: @DavidZemens, to be honest I don't know which exact way we could do so but I think it's feasible :)

Comment: @mike27015 I odn't think he wants to create a *copy* of the table in another sheet, only wants to replicate the table's dimensions, inserting rows while preserving all existing table data. In any case, you might try to avoid extended comment replies, especially posting inline code in comments, it's hard to read. Just suggest an "answer" instead.

Comment: If you would read the answer, you would see that `sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial(); ` can indicate what exactly he wants to copy, which in his case would be 1 row, means, cellmapp will be the range A4:E4. Means the table is not copied but only the given range, means it preserves all existing table data where he wants to copy it. For the row modification, he does another check, while using foreach loop that I gave to go through all sheets and check the amount of row content from 1 sheet and compare it with the 2nd sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution would be in C#, where you actually after you insert data in one sheet to replicate the same table content or a copy of that sheet into the destination sheet. Or by copytoclipboard, you take the any table and copy it to the desintation. Which solution are you looking for? C#, VBA?

```
sheet.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value); 
sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial();
```

Where cellmapp is the range where you want it to replace. If you text is to huge for the area, you can use sheet.Columns.AutoFit(); sheet.Rows.AutoFit(); This would be a C# solution, but would require a bit more of programming.

And for looping through the sheets:

```
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets) 
{ 
   workbook.Activate(); sheet.Activate(); foreach (Excel.Shape shape in sheet.Shapes)
   { } 
}
```

For the row, modification or switching place, you can simple move all your existing row values from one position to the right possible if you create a new row.

```
sheet.UsedRange.Copy(Missing.Value); //copy your existing row's 
sheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial(); // move them from B4 to C4
```